# Specify --no-highlight-code in Babel Require Hook options

Tags: babeljs

How to specify the `--no-highlight-code` option in Babel's Require Hook options object?

```
require('babel/register')({
    '--no-highlight-code': true,
    'no-highlight-code': true,
    'noHighlightCode': true,
});
require('./script');
```

All of those give the error `Unknown option: no-highlight-code`

It's an option present Babel's command line usage, so I'm not even sure if I'm supposed to use it like that, although the example page lists `blacklist` and `whitelist` could  be used ..

```
babel --help

  Usage: index [options] <files ...>

  Options:

    -h, --help                           output usage information
    -f, --filename [string]              filename to use when reading from stdin - this will be used in source-maps, errors etc
    --module-id [string]                 specify a custom name for module ids
    --retain-lines                       retain line numbers - will result in really ugly code
    --no-non-standard                    enable/disable support for JSX and Flow (on by default)
    --experimental                       allow use of experimental transformers
    --no-highlight-code                  enable/disable ANSI syntax highlighting of code frames (on by default)
    -e, --stage [number]                 ECMAScript proposal stage version to allow [0-4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option to disable highlighting code is (by default) on, and the command line option has the (added) prefix "no".

`require("babel/register")({ highlightCode: false })` is the way to disable highlighting code in parse time `SyntaxError`s when passing an object to `babel/register`.

Passing `{ highlightCode: true }` does nothing; the default is `true`.